# Mouse and keyboard stop working during debian live installation

Tags: debian, live-usb, gparted

I know there have been similar question, but neither applies to my situation.

I want to try/install debian. I downloaded a couple of live disc images (debian-live-7.8.0-amd64 with various desktop environments) and I copied them (one at once) to my usb stick using 
`cp image.iso /dev/sdX; sync`
The installer boots fine, I can choose from menu option (install, run live, run failsafe mode, etc.), at this point keyboard works fine. If I choose install, I go through language settings and so forth (using correctly working keyboard), up to the point when GParted launches. This is when input devices stop working - any touchpad, laptop/external keyboard or usb mouse actions cause no effect. I tried ctrl+alt+f1 to go into the command line interface, but no effect. The only I can do then is to reboot. 
I run both Ubuntu and windows on the very same laptop and never had any problems with built-in or usb peripherials.

What should I do to at least be able to gain some control during the installation? This happens in every image I try (KDE, GNOME, LXDE, xfce).

EDIT:

I just've tried to boot from the same usb at different machine (desktop PC). After choosing "run live" it just loaded debian desktop, without asking for language, keymap and without entering GParted, while on my laptop all those steps are present and lead to a computer frozen and GParted and not responding to anything.